# PDF creator (or any other) as shared printer does not work

Tags: pdf, printer

I need to run shared PDF printer on my Win2012 server. I have tryed BullZip and PDF creator with same result.

Printer installed, PDFs are created just fine for local server prints. Printer is shared, installed on client computer. Client can start print, task is visible on server. But no PDF...

I can see two files at c:\Windows\Temp\PDFCreator\Spool\ - .inf and .ps when client print is triggered. Also two files appers here c:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\ - .spl and .shp, but with zero lenght. Both folders have SYSTEM access set to full...

Any tips what should I try? Or tip to any other free PDF printer which may work as shared?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you need such a setup?

Comment: There is a really old sw able to print shared printer but not to PDF. SW update unrealistic so I thought this might work...